# Getting 'Property IpProtocol cannot be empty' error while creating security group using cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group

I am creating a basic security group using cloud formation on AWS but I am getting *Property IpProtocol cannot be empty.* error. Following is the yml code I am running:

```
Resources:
    testsecuritygroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties: 
      GroupName: test-group
      GroupDescription: test security group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
        - SourceSecurityGroupId: sg-xxxxxxxxxx
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0
      Tags:
        - Key: group
          Value: test
      VpcId: !ImportValue VPC
```

When I run create-stack command it is running successfully but the stack is rolled back with *CREATE_FAILED* status and *Property IpProtocol cannot be empty* error. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Hello there, are you sure that this error concerns exacly this security group? Don't you have any other SG in CloudFormation?

Comment: Thank you, I resolved the issue. I will post an answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue. To add a security group we have to create an Ingress rule and attach it to the security group instead of defining it in the security group.

```
Resources:
    test:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties: 
      VpcId: !ImportValue VPC
      GroupName: test-group
      GroupDescription: test security group
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      Tags:
        - Key: group
          Value: test
  TestInboundRule:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties: 
      GroupId: !GetAtt test.GroupId
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: 80
      ToPort: 80
      SourceSecurityGroupId: sg-xxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

Your cidr is not valid. It should be 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: This is one of the error in the code but not the reason for the error mentioned in question. I have posted the solution.